# How to list dirs containg a file?

Tags: find, posix

I'm trying to use find to list dirs with a certain file inside, but my dirs have spaces so I haven't found a solution.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. Can you be more specific?

Comment: If you're worried about compatibility, wouldn't a simple perl script using the standard File:Find module instead?  That would probably work reliably on any platform.

Comment: Phil, I'm not a perl programmer i'm a python programmer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I'm really understanding your question, have you tried:

```
find / -name "*what*" -exec dirname {} \;
```

This works for me even if my directories have spaces:

```
root:~# find / -name "*what*" -exec dirname {} \;
/usr/share/man/id/man1
...
...
/usr/share/man/ja/man1
/usr/share/man/it/man1
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/bin
/root/This is a Spaced Dir
```

Comment: This doesn't work on OS X

Answer (score 0):

POSIX dictates a rather weak `find` (seriously, it doesn't even have -print0).  Likewise, xargs won't have an `-0` option, and IEEE 1003.1-2008 considers `xargs -I {}` to be an X/Open System Interface extension (which both declares a string to substitute with arguments *and* converts xargs to using newlines for input argument separators).  Thus, assuming you actually want to *do something* with the path names other than printing them out and if you can only use base POSIX, you'll need to escape the spaces in the strings before passing them to xargs, thus:

```
find /startingdir -name 'file name' -exec dirname {} \; | sed 's/ /\\ /g' | xargs command
```

Note that you'll also need to escape quotes and backslashes, if you have directories that include these.  This could replace the sed command:

```
sed -e 's/\\/\\\\/' -e 's/ /\\ /g' -e 's/"/\\"/g' -e "s/'/\\\\'/g"
```

(Note the extra backslashes on the double quoted script.  Single quote strings use backslashes literally, but double quote strings will interpret backslashes, thus your shell will interpret `"\\\\"` as `\\` which sed needs for a literal `\`, while `'\\\\'` is interpreted as `\\\\` which sed needs for a literal `\\`.)  This will escape existing backslashes first, then escape spaces, double quotes and single quotes.

If you can use the X/Open System Interface extensions, then the first version (no quotes or backslashes) simplifies to:

```
find /startingdir -name 'file name' -exec dirname {} \; | xargs -I {} command {}
```

If you have quotes and backslashes in your directory names, these will still need to be escaped as above (but without escaping spaces).

Either way, if you have newlines in your directory names, then you've got bigger problems than I can help with.

***Edited to remove bash version, cleaned up based on input from Dennis Williamson***

Comment: There are many errors in your answer. To start with, your assignment to `IFS` won't work. You should never iterate over the output of `find` using a `for` loop. If you want to be portable and POSIX compliant, don't use `echo`. You *could* use `sed`, but why not use `dirname`. In one place you use `$()` which is specified by POSIX, but in another you use `backticks` which, while also POSIX, are less desirable. You fail to mention the `find` operator `-exec`. You fail to quote a variable containing a filename. The question is tagged `[posix]` but not tagged `[bash]` so `sh` should be assumed.

Comment: OK, I'll clean this up, though I'll be leaving it written for the assumption that he wants to do something with the list of directories, rather than just displaying them (otherwise, would it really merit mentioning spaces as a *problem*?).  I'll even take out the bash version of my answer, which I had written before seeing the posix tag.

Comment: Thanks, your first example worked. Now that I think about it sed would work for escaping spaces.

Answer (score 0):

This is from the fedora .bashrc file:

```
ff () {
       find . -name "*$@*" -print;
       }
```

Add this to your `.bashrc` and then reinitialize your bash shell

now you can use `ff <whatever > \ <whatever>`

The `\` is the escape sequence to escape special characters.

Answer (score 0):

`zsh` is not my preferred shell, but for this task its **-function is invincible:

```
zsh -c "'ls **/'the file name'"
```

Or even:

```
zsh -c "ls **/*'file name'"
```